# How to join values from dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have dictionary code as follows:

```
int entry=0;
string[] numbers ={"123","123","123","456","123"};
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (string number in numbers)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey("ABC"))
    {

    }
    else if (!dictionary.ContainsKey("ABC") && entry==0)
    {
        dictionary.Add("ABC", new List<string>());
        dictionary["ABC"].Add(number);
        entry = 1;
    }
    else if (!dictionary.ContainsKey("ABC") && entry == 1)
    {
        dictionary["ABC"].Add(number);
    }
}
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key={0},Value = {1}", kvp.Key,kvp.Value);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I want output like as follows `Key="ABC",Value="123,456"` i.e. I need to print all the dictionary values only once without repeat. In above string array 123 came 4 times.But I want to print that only one time and need 456 also and also joint that values with comma(",").So I need output like `Key="ABC",Value="123,456"`. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: suggestion: if you just want to add distinct `numbers` in your dictionary in the first place, why don't you use it like this instead of the big logic : `dictionary["ABC"] = numbers.Distinct().ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to print all the dictionary values only once without repeat.

Use `Distinct` method.

> joint that values with comma(",")

Use `String.Join` method.

```
foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Key={0},Value = {1}", 
         kvp.Key, 
         String.Join(", " kvp.Value.Distinct())
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
foreach(var value in dictionary.Values.Distinct())
{
  names = String.Join(", ", value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following for loop variable is incorrect, I think:

```
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in dictionary)
           {
        Console.WriteLine("Key={0},Value = {1}", kvp.Key,kvp.Value);
           }
```

It should read: then note the difference in the writeline

```
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,List<string>> kvp in dictionary)
           {
        Console.WriteLine("Key={0},Value = {1}", kvp.Key,string.Join(",", kvp.Value.ToArray()));
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple linq to flatten and join all your dictionary contents:

```
var result = string.Join(" - ", dic.Select(kvp => string.Format("Key={0}, Values={1}", kvp.Key, string.Join(", ",kvp.Value.Distinct()))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this array :

```
string[] numbers = {"123","123","123","456","123"};
```

Add another array as :

```
string[] uniqueNumbers = numbers.Distinct().ToArray();
```

and now use this array with unique values to add to the dictionary.